# How to use two model forms on one view

Tags: python, django, web

I'm still new to django, I'm working on a project where I'll need users to enter some information about houses they want to rent out. I want the users to upload a minimum of 6 pictures and from what I've gathered, the best way to do this on django is to use two models, one collects basic information about the houses and the second stores images of the houses. How am I supposed to code the views.py. I've tried all to no avail.

**forms.py**

```py
class MyHouseEditForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:        
        model = Myhouses        
        fields = ('name_of_accomodation', 
                  'type_of_apartment','Number_of_rooms', 'house_rent', 
                  'availability', 'location', 'nearest_institution', 
                  'description',) 


class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('__all__' )
```

**models.py**

```py
class Myhouses(models.Model):

    Available = 'A'
    Not_Available = 'NA'
    Availability = (
        (Available, 'Available'),
        (Not_Available, 'Not_Available'),
    )

    Flat = 'F'
    Self_contained = 's'
    Bungalow = 'b'
    Mini_flat = 's'
    Duplex = 'D'
    Room = (
        (Flat, 'Flat'),
        (Self_contained, 'Self_contained'),
        (Bungalow, 'Bungalow'),
        (Mini_flat, 'Mini_flat'),
        (Duplex, 'Duplex'),
    )

    time = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now, blank = True)
    name_of_accomodation = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    type_of_apartment = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Room, )
    Number_of_rooms = house_rent = models.IntegerField()
    house_rent = models.IntegerField()
    availability = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Availability, default=Available,)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    nearest_institution = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='author')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_of_accomodation

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('search-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-time"]

class Image(models.Model):
    myhouses = models.ForeignKey(Myhouses, related_name='images', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/')
```

**views.py**

```py
def addlisting(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        Hform = MyHouseEditForm(request.POST, files=request.FILES, )
        Iform = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES, )
        if Hform.is_valid() and Iform.is_valid():    
            Houses = Hform.save(commit=False)
            Houses.author=request.user
            Houses.save()

            image = iform.save(commit=False)
            Houses.image.myhouses = myhouses
            Houses.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Listing Created Succesfully successfully')
            return redirect('addlisting')           
    else:        
        Hform = MyHouseEditForm()
        Iform = ImageForm()

    return render(request, 'houses/addlisting.html', {'Hform':Hform, 'Iform': Iform},  )
```

Comment: Can you explain what happens when you run your code above, such as any errors? I can see some potential problems (such as you have iform.save instead of Iform.save)

Comment: Make use of [inline-formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)

Comment: As said above, you're code has typing errors, iform instead of Iform, also indentation errors. And if you want to add a minimum of 6 images, that will not work as your image model (and form) only has one image.